# What is the effect of data scaling when compared between kNN, naive Bayes or logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, naive-bayes, k-nearest-neighbour

I am a complete noob and have just started with machine learning. However there was this one question I faced which I was unable to answer.

What is the effect of data (feature) scaling on the three classifiers, namely kNN, naive Bayes and logistic regression? Would there be any difference between the optimum parameters found by cross validation and evaluation results for scaled vs raw data.

It would be a real great help if some one can explain it graphically.

Comment: Why don't trying to do it yourself? For instance, you could take a dataset and try to fit those models with and without feature scaling and see what happens.

Comment: @utobi I don't want to get into the programming stuff. All I just need is a little explanation on why the optimum parameters would change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of these ML methods is effected differently by scaling.  Naive Bayes is basically unaffected.  Naive Bayes sets the priors based on the data you give it, so it will scale those priors to match your data.

Logistic regression is in the middle.  If you are doing simple logistic regression, the model can increase or decrease the coefficients on the features as needed to effectively scale the features using the coefficients.  There are two potential negative effects of not scaling though.  First, it may take a lot longer for the model to converge using gradient decent.  Since one unit of movement has a much bigger effect in one feature dimension than the other (see image below) the decent will either bounce around in the smaller dimension and have difficulty hitting the optimum value, or it will crawl slowly along the larger dimension taking a long time to creep up to the optimum.

[image: Optimization function with different scale parameters]

Second, if you use regularization, it will effect your model.  Since regularization penalizes the size of the coefficients, you will effectively penalize small values more than large values because you need a bigger coefficient on a small value to get the same effect as on a big one.

KNN is going to be effected the most.  Since KNN just looks at the euclidean distance between data points scale matters hugely.  Imagine you have one set of features `A` with values ranging between 0 and 10<sup>5</sup> and another `B` with values ranging from 0 to 1.  `A` will dominate this model because even if you have values at the maximum possible difference possible between the `B` values it will only be equivalent to a minuscule difference in `A`.

Comment: I wonder whether common software implementations of logistic regression scale the variables before computations and undo the scaling afterwards. I think the "glmnet" package in R does something like that for penalized logistic regression, for example.

Comment: In accordance with the answer I assume that logistic regression just adds a little overhead in terms of time finding out the optimum parameters as it takes times for the model to converge.
Would the linear regression behave the same way as logistic regression.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, in unregularized both linear and logistic regression, the difference should just be in the computational time of selecting coefficients (though the coefficients selected will be different to compensate for the scale of the values).  However the time increase can be very significant depending on the model being built.  Since scaling is computationally cheap, and won't hurt the model, there is no reason not to do it.

Comment: @RichardHardy, I don't think `glmnet` does.  I just ran an experiment were I made a model with `glmnet` on the example data from the docs, and then took the `x` matrix and multiplied each column by a different value and made the model again.  Even though `y` was unchanged and the only difference in `x` was scale, the model made very different predictions and the order in which the variables had coefficients go to zero was different.  It wouldn't make sense for `glmnet` to do this by default anyway as the user might want some variables to carry a heavier penalty.

Comment: Interesting. I see that in the function `glmnet`, the argument `standardize` is set to `TRUE` by default.

Comment: That is interesting, maybe I set up my experiment wrong, or maybe since the example just uses a random number generator for features, it is highly unstable and small differences in approximation of means and SD based on scaling make big difference in the model.  It is also possible they mean some other form of standardization (such as scaling between 0 and 1).